# How can i show my JSON data to another html page in html table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

This is on the first page:

```
scoreSubmit() {
  var name = prompt("Unesi svoje ime:");
  var objekat = {
    "name": name,
    "score": score
  };
  var myJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("textvalue"));
  myJSON[myJSON.length] = objekat;

  var sort = false;
  while (!sort) {
    sort = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length - 1; i++) {
      if (myJSON[i + 1].score > myJSON[i].score) {
        var temp = myJSON[i];
        myJSON[i] = myJSON[i + 1];
        myJSON[i + 1] = temp;
        sort = false;
      }
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem("textvalue", JSON.stringify(objekat));
}
```

and this is code on my second page

```
  var myJSON=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("textvalue"));

  var bodycontent="";

  for(var i =0;i<myJSON.length;i++){
               bodycontent +="<tr>";
               bodyContent += "<td>" + (i + 1) + ".</td><td class='name'>" + myJSON[i].name + "</td><td>" + myJSON[i].score + "</td>";
               bodyContent += "</tr>";


   }
   document.getElementById("leaderboardBody").innerHTML =bodycontent;
```

but for some reason, if JSON data doesn't show up on table.Do you know where i'm faulting? Any help needs me a lot!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @shiva IMHO the intended purpose of OP's code is pretty clear - to generate some data on one page, and display it on a different page in the website, using localstorage to store the data between requests. I think they just made a small mistake when storing the data - see my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem("textvalue", JSON.stringify(objekat));
```

looks wrong. Surely you intended to write

```
localStorage.setItem("textvalue", JSON.stringify(myJSON));
```

?

Otherwise it will just write one object value into localstorage, and the whole purpose of retrieving an existing list, adding to it and sorting is pointless. Also, if you try to process a single object using your second-page code, it will not have a length (because it isn't an array) and so the loop will not run in order to create the HTML.

Comment: I checked that, still doesn't work. I try to create leaderboard for js game and my idea is when the game is over, user will write a name on input field and together with score points will be written on the other html  page when they will be sorted by the highest score

Comment: "doesn't work" how, specifically? What debugging have you done? Do you get an error message of any kind? Have you tried to log any values to see what is actually being saved and loaded from localstorage? Are the two pages in question both served from the same Origin (i.e. the same protocol, hostname and port number)? You need to narrow down the problem. I can't run your code to find it for myself, and I can't fix "doesn't work" because that isn't an error message or a problem description.

Comment: Can i send you my project ?

Comment: No, I'm not going to wade through all of your code and run it to find the specifics. **You** need to debug it, and then provide the necessary information here on this page. Then it will be useful not only to you, but to others reading in future (which is the real purpose of this site). Thanks. Did you understand all of the things I asked you to check for, above? If you're not very familiar with debugging your code, now would be a great time to learn. It's a vital skill for any programmer.

Comment: Then if you're not sure what to do with the results of your debugging, or how to resolve the issues it identifies, you can add the information to your question so that we can help you resolve it fully.

Comment: Yes, i understand what are you asking me. I debugged my code and the isssue is length, exactly it shows that is length undefined, which i think is answer where you telling me that is length not a array. I'm searching for some another solution,to be more precisely, leaderboard of results to show on the same page, not on the defferent one

Comment: Actually, to help you out a bit, I made a simplified example (where we do all of it in one page, to concentrate on getting the actual code right). Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/1nLsx0bf/ . As you can see by watching the Console while you run it, it fails pretty quickly because you aren't checking whether any value already exists or not in localStorage before you try to use it. if there's no existing storage value you need to create it. Additionally, to add new items to an array you should use the "push" method. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1nLsx0bf/1/

Comment: There are other errors still, so you can carry on debugging from there. Once you've got the actual code right, you can move on to loading it on different pages.